# Migrating to Azure SQL - how integrate domain service accounts?

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

I am required to migrate an on-prem ASP.Net web application with its SQL Server 2019 backend to Azure.

The Web application initial migration must be IaaS (Windows VMs running IIS).
The SQL 2019 has to be Azure SQL PaaS (Not Azure SQL Managed instance).

The existing on-prem Web application has several virtual directories, and each application in a virtual directory, is in a separate IIS app pool.
Each app pool is run under the context of a different domain service account.
Connection to the SQL databases is via integrated security.

In the current on-prem solution, the domain service accounts are added as logins to the SQL Server and each has permissions to one or more of the databases (Execute / Connect permissions; addition to datareader role etc).

I believe there will have a domain join to Azure AD, so the on-prem AD service accounts will be accessible in azure (as far as I can understand).

SQL Azure does not support CREATE LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\MYSVCACCOUNT] FROM WINDOWS;

Is there a way I can setup the existing on-prem domain accounts with the access, permissions and roles in the SQL PaaS solution, to mirror the current on-prem setup?

Alternatively, could someone could help me identify resources for best practice for the architecture described.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a a few good posts that assisted me to understand all available options:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage